# Type checking calling identical overloaded signatures in base class from derived class

Tags: python, overloading, mypy, python-typing

I am using MyPy 1.2.0 with the settings:

```toml
[tool.mypy]
show_column_numbers   = true
disallow_any_expr     = true
disallow_untyped_defs = true
```

The code has attributes where the type of one class attribute is correlated to the value of another attribute:

```python
from typing import List, Literal, overload


class Base:
    null: bool
    enum: List[str | None] | List[str] | None

    @overload
    def __init__(
        self: "Base", null: Literal[True] = ..., enum: List[str | None] | None = ...,
    ) -> None:
        pass

    @overload
    def __init__(
        self: "Base", null: Literal[False] = ..., enum: List[str] | None = ...,
    ) -> None:
        pass

    def __init__(
        self: "Base", null: bool = False, enum: List[str | None] | List[str] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.null = null
        self.enum = enum


class Derived(Base):
    @overload
    def __init__(
        self: "Derived", null: Literal[True] = ..., enum: List[str | None] | None = ...,
    ) -> None:
        pass

    @overload
    def __init__(
        self: "Derived", null: Literal[False] = ..., enum: List[str] | None = ...,
    ) -> None:
        pass

    def __init__(
        self: "Derived", null: bool = False, enum: List[str | None] | List[str] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(null=null, enum=enum)
```

MyPy gives the error:

```error
overload-with-types.py:43:9: error: No overload variant of "__init__" of "Base" matches argument types "bool", "Union[List[Optional[str]], List[str], None]"  [call-overload]
overload-with-types.py:43:9: note: Possible overload variants:
overload-with-types.py:43:9: note:     def __init__(self, null: Literal[True] = ..., enum: Optional[List[Optional[str]]] = ...) -> None
overload-with-types.py:43:9: note:     def __init__(self, null: Literal[False] = ..., enum: Optional[List[str]] = ...) -> None
```

I can fix the error using explicit casts for each possible overload:

```python
    def __init__(
        self: "Derived", null: bool = False, enum: List[str | None] | List[str] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        if null:
            super().__init__(null=null, enum=cast(List[str | None] | None, enum))
        else:
            super().__init__(null=null, enum=cast(List[str] | None, enum))
```

However, if there are n correlated sets of binary type choices in the method signature then there will be 2<sup>n</sup> overloads and a corresponding number of different calls to `super().__init__` from the derived class. The number of different overloads is expected but MyPy (and pyright) not recognising that the base and derived class have the same overloaded signatures and requiring explicit casts is not expected.

Is there a pythonic way to ensure that the corresponding signatures of base- and derived-classes are recognised during type checking that does not require writing out multiple `super().__init__(...)` and use `cast` for each possible overloaded signature? (Without relaxing the strict options used during type checking)

Comment: While this is a valid concern, I don't really find this surprising. The way overloads work in Python, the body of the actual implementation of a method and its overloaded _signatures_ are two different things and I doubt any type checker considers one to be relevant to the other. Whether or not it _should_ consider the overload variants in the function body is a good question though. Something akin to [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) but for all arguments could solve this problem.